# Is there any literature on selection of dimensions for word embeddings?

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings

I'm looking for any papers/articles on how the word embedding dimensions affect the performance in NLP tasks. Specifically, has anyone ever used low dimensional(<10) word embeddings and achieved good results?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please see [Effective Dimensionality Reduction for Word Embeddings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.03629) ([code](https://github.com/vyraun/Half-Size))

Comment: I think this link might be helpful [Link](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/290/5500/2323)